# Trying to link table between Access DBs using VBA. Getting ISAM not found error

Tags: vba, ms-access, linked-tables, isam

I have a split database where both the front end and back end are accdb files.  Because one of my tables uses the `AppendOnly = Yes` property, I cannot use the link table manager or the refreshlink property when I move the backend. The backend moves from time to time because my IT loves to reshuffle servers.

So my solution is to write a function which prompts for the backend location, deletes all the currently linked tables, and then loops through all the backend tables and links them to the frontend. On this last part I receive a run time error 3170 could not find suitable ISAM. I don't know why.

Code is below:

```
Public Function MoveDB()

'this function will replace the linked table manager.  It will open a file select dialog box to allow the user to pick the new location of the DB backend.
'It will then break all the current links and then recreate them.  We need to do this vice use the relink function because the cases table uses AutoAppend which stores old path data
' and breaks the relink function which is why linked table manager does not work.

' FileDialog Requires a reference to Microsoft Office 11.0 Object Library.

'variables to get the database path
Dim fDialog As Office.FileDialog
Dim varFile As Variant
Dim DriveLetter As String
Dim NetworkPath As String
Dim DrivePath As String
Dim SubPath As String


'variables to link the database
Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim BEdb As DAO.Database
Dim oldtdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim tblName As String
Dim newtdf As DAO.TableDef
Dim BEtdf As DAO.TableDef


Set db = CurrentDb()

' Set up the File Dialog.
Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
With fDialog

   ' Do not Allow user to make multiple selections in dialog box
  .AllowMultiSelect = False

  'set the default folder that is opened
  .InitialFileName = CurrentProject.Path & "\BE"

  ' Set the title of the dialog box.
  .Title = "Please select the Database Backend"

  ' Clear out the current filters, and add our own.
  .Filters.Clear
  .Filters.Add "Access Databases", "*.accdb"

  ' Show the dialog box. If the .Show method returns True, the
  ' user picked a file. If the .Show method returns
  ' False, the user clicked Cancel.
  If .Show = True Then

 'We need to determine the full network path (including server name) to the DB backend.  The reason is that different users may have the share drive mapped with different letters.
'If the backend is mapped using the drive letter of the user moving the DB then other users may not have a valid path.  The full network path is universal


'Get the mapped drive letter from the path of the selected DB file
     DriveLetter = Left$(Trim(fDialog.SelectedItems(1)), 2)
'Get the path of the selected DB file minus the drive letter
     SubPath = Mid$(Trim(fDialog.SelectedItems(1)), 3)
'Get the full network path of the mapped drive letter
     DrivePath = GETNETWORKPATH(DriveLetter)
'Combine the drive path and the sub path to get the full path to the selected DB file
     NetworkPath = DrivePath & SubPath
     'MsgBox (NetworkPath)
  Else
     MsgBox "You clicked Cancel in the file dialog box."
  End If
End With
     'Now we need to delete all the linked tables

For Each oldtdf In db.TableDefs
    With oldtdf
        If oldtdf.Attributes And dbAttachedODBC Or oldtdf.Attributes And dbAttachedTable Then
        'this is a linked table
            tblName = .Name
            DoCmd.DeleteObject acTable, tblName
        End If
    End With
Next oldtdf
tblName = ""


'Now we link all the tables from the backend to the front end
Set BEdb = OpenDatabase(NetworkPath)
For Each BEtdf In BEdb.TableDefs
    tblName = BEtdf.Name
    If Left(tblName, 4) <> "~TMP" Then
        Set newtdf = db.CreateTableDef(strTable)
        newtdf.Connect = "Database = " & NetworkPath
        newtdf.SourceTableName = tblName
        newtdf.Name = tblName
    db.TableDefs.Append newtdf
    End If
Next BEtdf

End Function
```

The error occurs on the

```
db.TableDefs.Append newtdf
```

line. I'm looking to either make this code work, or a way around the known bug that prevents refreshing links when using the `AppendOnly=Yes` property.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: may be this will be useful: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/209805

Comment: The code I am working on is currently on my desktop for development.  so the result is:    Database = \Users\[My UserName]\Desktop\Database project files\BE\ACCLOGWINGSAU_be.accdb

Comment: winghei found the issue.  But as you predicted I am trying to link system tables I did not know existed.  I'll fix that by storing the table names in an array before I delete them and then loop through them when I create the links so that I only link the specific tables I need.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are just missing the semicolon on your string and remove extra spaces

```
newtdf.Connect = ";Database=" & NetworkPath
```

Comment: I tried that.  Adding the semi-colon causes a 3001 invalid argument error.  But thank you for the reply.

Comment: remove the spaces ";Databases=" & . It should be fine since i got the same error you had when there are spaces

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use [DoCmd.TransferDatabase](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196455.aspx) method and be sure to leave out the MSys tables as they have no direct application use between split files:

```
If Left(tblName, 4) <> "~TMP" And Left(tblName, 4) <> "MSys" Then
     DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, "Microsoft Access", NetworkPath, _
                            acTable, tblName, tblName, False
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

found this and worked for me

```
DAODataSet.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM Country IN "" ";DATABASE=C:\SIMPLE.MDB;PWD=MyPassword"';
DAODataSet.Open;
```